# How can I substitute a named route for a resource path in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a named route to the user's inbox, which is maintained by the messages resource. I want to make sure that the users can only access their inbox from my named path, and remove "/messages" as an option.

```
  resources :messages
  match "/u/:nickname/inbox" => "messages#index", :as=>:inbox
```

Is there a simple way of doing that? Do I have to just create a matching path for "/messages"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

I'd create a path for messages and remove `resources :messages`

This approach will delete all the normal routes for messages and you'll have to re-add the ones you want available.

**Solution 2:**

Only remove the index option for the routes and allow all other standards routes to be the same.

```
resources :messages, :except => :index
match "/u/:nickname/inbox" => "messages#index", :as=>:inbox
```

Comment: When I remove resources line, I get "No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"messages"}" error on the new template.

Comment: Because we deleted the resources map you'll have to manually re-add the routes you want available for messages.